# Converting Utf8 to UCS2 bytes array

Tags: c#, arrays, encoding, utf, ucs2

I looking for a code sample to convert UTF8 (Bengali characters) to convert in UCS2 byte array. Is there I direct way to get this along? 
Somehow, I got the UCS2 conversion but as a string value not in a byte array.

For instance:

```
byte[] message;
message = UTF2UCS.GetBytes
          ( smsText.Substring(0, 
           smsText.Length > maxLength ? maxLength : smsText.Length));
```

My return output should be like this.

thanks

Answer (score 2):

Something like this is the best you could get. According to [this link](https://web.archive.org/web/20150802070702/http://www.datamystic.com/textpipe/htmlhelp/conversion%20filters/codepages.htm):

```
//1200  Unicode UCS-2 Little-Endian (BMP of ISO 10646)
//1201  Unicode UCS-2 Big-Endian

Encoding bytesUCS = Encoding.GetEncoding(1201);
Encoding utf8 = Encoding.UTF8;
byte[] utf8Bytes = utf8.GetBytes(UTF2UCS);
byte[] isoBytes = Encoding.Convert(utf8, bytesUCS, utf8Bytes);
```

Comment: Hi,
I used similar code here.
Encoding bytesUCS = Encoding.GetEncoding(1200);
Encoding utf8 = Encoding.UTF8;
byte[] utf8Bytes = utf8.GetBytes(smsText);
message = Encoding.Convert(utf8, bytesUCS, utf8Bytes);

but it is not giving correct Byte Array. I am sending text "আমার নাম রাজ হয়" whose byte array in UCS2 should have this string  "098609ae09be09b0002009a809be09ae002009b009be099c002009b909af09bc" but using the above code I am getting something else

Comment: I did use that for cyrilic in a project of mine and it worked just fine. I'm sorry to hear it's of no use to you :(

Answer (score 2):

```
 byte[] utcs2Bytes = System.Text.Encoding.Convert(System.Text.Encoding.UTF8, System.Text.Encoding.Unicode, newArray);
```

newArray is the destinated bytearray for storing the encoded byte

Answer (score -1):

Use [`Encoding.GetBytes`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.encoding.getbytes(v=vs.90).aspx) and [`Encoding.GetString`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.encoding.getstring(v=vs.90).aspx):

```
byte[] bengaliUtf8 = ....
string stringValue = UTF8Encoding.GetString(bengaliUtf8);
byte[] utf16Value = UnicodeEncoding.GetBytes(stringValue);
```

UTF-16 ('Unicode') is the best you can get, C# has no support for UCS-2. If your input has no surrogate characters then the output of UTF-16 matches UCS-2.

Comment: Can you explain a bit on Surrogate Characters. I am using Bengali Characters

Comment: See for example [How do I convert a UTF-16 surrogate pair such as <D800 DC00> to UTF-8?](http://unicode.org/faq/utf_bom.html#utf8-4). UTF-8 may contain surrogate 4-byte sequences that will  translate to UTF-16 surrogate pairs, which make invalid UCS-2. Only you can decide if your source text has or has not surrogates in it. The normal [Bengali block](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bengali_(Unicode_block)) has no surrogates in it.

Comment: My input does not have Surrogate chars. Pl can you complete your first line which says |byte[] bengaliUtf8 = ...."